# php $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] get a wrong value

Tags: php, nginx

I access the url ：http://192.168.94.128:81/index.php/login?a=123

I think “$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']" value should be '/index.php'
but now it's '/index.php/login'

I think for a long time, didn't know the answer

Who knows why?

URL : http://192.168.94.128:81/index.php/login?a=123

my nginx config is：

```
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  localhost;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
    location / {
        root           /home/www/ebook;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

other nginx config is default setting

Comment: @RiggsFolly  
Thank you very much for your answer, I have read the docs before But the doc said SCRIPT_NAME is "Contains the current script's path" My current file is index.php The SCRIPT_NAME isn't should be "/index.php"? Why are there "login"? Is my understanding is wrong? Thank you very much for your help. –

Comment: @bub I think above comment is aimed at you

Comment: Are you sure you are not using PHP_SELF ? Otherwise your issue"could" be related to nginx(Never happened t me at all). Does this happen to you also using apache?